# I am trying to run a query in php its working in phpMyAdmin but not in script

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, backend, sql-like

Iam trying to fetch related articles for a blog based project
Query :

```
 $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE cat_id like '%$cat_arr[i]%' AND NOT post_id = '$postid'");
```

Problem :
When ran in phpMyAdmin as a normal query it is fetching 3-4 rows as required but in scripts, it is fetching all rows in the posts table

Comment: echo query in your code check the query with what you have written in PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: `$cartData = $cat_arr[$i]; //or $cat_arr['i'];
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE cat_id like '%$cartData%' AND NOT post_id = '$postid'");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the variable `'%$cat_arr[i]%` is blank.

So if you are running the query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE cat_id like '%$cat_arr[i]%' AND NOT post_id = '$postid'");
```

Instead of two conditions, only one condition `post_id = '$postid'` is getting into consideration.

If we pass blank in `LIKE %%`, it is equal to not adding the conditon.

So, best solution is to evaluate the variable first:

```
if (isset($cat_arr[i]) && ! empty($cat_arr[i]) && ! empty($postid)) {
 $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE cat_id like '%$cat_arr[i]%' AND NOT post_id = '$postid'");
}
else {
 // Another condition
}
```

Comment: `NOT post_id =...`